# How to list all branches from a Git repo into the own console

Tags: linux, git

Everytime I run `git branch -a`, an editor (I suppose **nano**) is opened to show the output, but I wish the output is by using the same console (like **cat**). How do I get it?

My info:

- OS: Manjaro Linux x86_64
- Kernel: 5.12.9-1-MANJARO
- Shell: zsh 5.8
- Git: 2.32.0

Comment: Do you have `nano` configured as the pager for Git to use? I can't imagine why else Git wouldn't just write to standard output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems it's the `"pager"` of Git that shows up here (if you have many branches).

You can try if one of these works for you (see [the doc of `git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pagerltcmdgt)):

- `git --no-pager branch -a`
- `GIT_PAGER=cat git branch -a`
- `git config --global pager.branch false` or more aggressively `git config --global core.pager cat`; then `git branch -a`

FTR, the "pager" that is triggered in practice is normally `less` (not `nano`): see [this other section of `git config`'s doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corepager).

Comment: The OP might also consider setting the F and X options when using `less`. The F option makes `less` exit immediately if the entire output fits in one "page", and the `X` option inhibits any alternate-screen-mode that is otherwise annoyingly impossible to turn off in macOS Terminal, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

if you just try to pipe `|` to another program, does it behave the way you expect?

```sh
git branch -a | cat
```

(perhaps a non-[useless use of cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat)?)